Rotating and Scaling TikZ's `\pics` Around Its Center
Following this @JasperHabicht's answer, I'm trying to use TikZ's \pics for my Shogi diagrams future package.
In Shogi, to help differentiate the pieces, the ones with more value are bigger. And the opponent's pieces are upside down to you. So I'm trying to incorporate rotation and scaling parameters into the pieces. But using them directly yields 2 problems:

The piece outline is not centered.
The piece outline is not rotated with its center axis.

Here's an example picture of the kings getting scaled and rotated:

Here's my adaptation of @JasperHabicht's code:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{luatexja}

\usepackage{tikz}

% From [this answer by @JasperHabicht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730333/64441).
\pgfkeys{
  /tikz/pics/shogi grid/.style={
    code={
      \draw (0, 0) grid[step = 1] 
        (\shogiBoardDimension, \shogiBoardDimension * \shogiHeightMultiplier); 
    },
  },
  /tikz/pics/shogi piece/.style={
    code={
      \pgfkeys{/phili/shogiban/piece/.cd, #1}
      \draw[
        draw   = \shogiPieceColor,
        scale  = \shogiPieceScale,
        rotate = \shogiPieceRotate,
      ]
        (0.5, 0.85) --
        (0.22, 0.73) --
        (0.2, 0.2) --
        (0.8, 0.2) --
        (0.78, 0.73) --
        cycle;
      \node[
        font   = \fontsize{7.5 pt}{7.5 pt}\selectfont,
        color  = \shogiPieceColor,
        scale  = \shogiPieceScale,
        % rotate = \shogiPieceRotate,
      ] at (0.5, 0.5) {\rotatebox{\shogiPieceRotate}{\shogiPieceText}};
    }
  },
  /phili/shogiban/.cd, 
    board dimension/.store in   = \shogiBoardDimension,
    board dimension             = 5 cm,
    height multiplier/.store in = \shogiHeightMultiplier,
    height multiplier           = 1.2,
    initial scale/.style        = {
      /tikz/x                   = \shogiBoardDimension / 9 cm * 1 cm,
      /tikz/y                   = \shogiBoardDimension * \shogiHeightMultiplier / 9 cm * 1 cm
    },
    piece/color/.store in       = \shogiPieceColor, 
    piece/color                 = black,
    piece/text/.store in        = \shogiPieceText,
    piece/text                  = A,
    piece/scale/.store in       = \shogiPieceScale,
    piece/scale                 = 1.0,
    piece/rotate/.store in      = \shogiPieceRotate,
    piece/rotate                = 0,
}

\newenvironment{shogiban}[1][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[/phili/shogiban/.cd, #1, initial scale]
    \pic{shogi grid};
}{
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{shogiban}[board dimension = 5 cm]
    \pic at (0, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 香}}; % Lance
    \pic at (1, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 桂}}; % Knight
    \pic at (2, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 銀}}; % Silver
    \pic at (3, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 金}}; % Gold
    \pic at (4, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 玉, scale = 1.1}}; % King (sente)
    \pic at (5, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 金}}; % Gold
    \pic at (6, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 銀}}; % Silver
    \pic at (7, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 桂}}; % Knight
    \pic at (8, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 香}}; % Lance

    \pic at (1, 1) {shogi piece = {text = 角}}; % Bishop
    \pic at (7, 1) {shogi piece = {text = 飛}}; % Bishop

    \foreach \x in {0, ..., 8} {
      \pic at (\x, 2) {shogi piece = {text = 歩}}; % Pawn  
    }

    \pic at (1, 3) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = 馬}}; % Promoted Bishop (Dragon Horse)
    \pic at (7, 3) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = 龍}}; % Promoted Rook (Dragon King)
    \pic at (3, 3) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = 全}}; % Promoted Silver (Gold)
    \pic at (4, 3) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = 今}}; % Promoted Knight
    \pic at (5, 3) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = 杏}}; % Promoted Lance
    \pic at (4, 4) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = と}}; % Promoted Pawn

    \pic at (4, 8) {shogi piece = {text = 王, scale = 1.1, rotate = 180}}; % King (gote)
  \end{shogiban}
\end{document}


Should both the text as well as the shape be rotated? I would create a custom shape, the work is worth it, I believe.

@Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, both the text and the shape should be rotated.

You could just shift the whole \pic by (0.5, 0.5) to have its origin at the center of a cell of the board and unshift the stuff inside the \pic (that is: shift the drawing by (-0.5, -0.5) and place the node at (0, 0)). Once the origin is in the center of a cell, the effect of scaling and rotating will be as intended:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\usepackage{tikz}

% From [this answer by @JasperHabicht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730333/64441).
\pgfkeys{
  /tikz/pics/shogi grid/.style={
    code={
      \draw (0, 0) grid[step = 1] 
        (\shogiBoardDimension, \shogiBoardDimension * \shogiHeightMultiplier); 
    },
  },
  /tikz/pics/shogi piece/.style={
    code={
      \pgfkeys{/tikz/shift={(0.5, 0.5)}, /phili/shogiban/piece/.cd, #1}
      \draw[
        draw   = \shogiPieceColor,
        scale  = \shogiPieceScale,
        rotate = \shogiPieceRotate,
      ]
        (0, 0.35) --
        (-0.28, 0.23) --
        (-0.3, -0.3) --
        (0.3, -0.3) --
        (0.28, 0.23) --
        cycle;
      \node[
        font   = \fontsize{7.5 pt}{7.5 pt}\selectfont,
        color  = \shogiPieceColor,
        scale  = \shogiPieceScale,
        % rotate = \shogiPieceRotate,
      ] at (0, 0) {\rotatebox{\shogiPieceRotate}{\shogiPieceText}};
    }
  },
  /phili/shogiban/.cd, 
    board dimension/.store in   = \shogiBoardDimension,
    board dimension             = 5 cm,
    height multiplier/.store in = \shogiHeightMultiplier,
    height multiplier           = 1.2,
    initial scale/.style        = {
      /tikz/x                   = \shogiBoardDimension / 9 cm * 1 cm,
      /tikz/y                   = \shogiBoardDimension * \shogiHeightMultiplier / 9 cm * 1 cm
    },
    piece/color/.store in       = \shogiPieceColor, 
    piece/color                 = black,
    piece/text/.store in        = \shogiPieceText,
    piece/text                  = A,
    piece/scale/.store in       = \shogiPieceScale,
    piece/scale                 = 1.0,
    piece/rotate/.store in      = \shogiPieceRotate,
    piece/rotate                = 0,
}

\newenvironment{shogiban}[1][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[/phili/shogiban/.cd, #1, initial scale]
    \pic{shogi grid};
}{
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{shogiban}[board dimension = 5 cm]
    \pic at (0, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 香}}; % Lance
    \pic at (1, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 桂}}; % Knight
    \pic at (2, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 銀}}; % Silver
    \pic at (3, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 金}}; % Gold
    \pic at (4, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 玉, scale = 1.1}}; % King (sente)
    \pic at (5, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 金}}; % Gold
    \pic at (6, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 銀}}; % Silver
    \pic at (7, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 桂}}; % Knight
    \pic at (8, 0) {shogi piece = {text = 香}}; % Lance

    \pic at (1, 1) {shogi piece = {text = 角}}; % Bishop
    \pic at (7, 1) {shogi piece = {text = 飛}}; % Bishop

    \foreach \x in {0, ..., 8} {
      \pic at (\x, 2) {shogi piece = {text = 歩}}; % Pawn  
    }

    \pic at (1, 3) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = 馬}}; % Promoted Bishop (Dragon Horse)
    \pic at (7, 3) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = 龍}}; % Promoted Rook (Dragon King)
    \pic at (3, 3) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = 全}}; % Promoted Silver (Gold)
    \pic at (4, 3) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = 今}}; % Promoted Knight
    \pic at (5, 3) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = 杏}}; % Promoted Lance
    \pic at (4, 4) {shogi piece = {color = red, text = と}}; % Promoted Pawn

    \pic at (4, 8) {shogi piece = {text = 王, scale = 1.1, rotate = 180}}; % King (gote)
  \end{shogiban}
\end{document}



Excellent stuff as always. Thank you, @JasperHabicht! I wish I had used your \pics logic for my other goban code, the code would have been much shorter.

@psygo It is never too late to rewrite and optimise code … but there are also often different ways to solve a problem with TeX that are equally reasonable
